# Function until->transformed (Racket)

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Given a special form until

```
(until
exp1
...
expn
test)
```

exp1, . . . , expn are calculated sequentially, and then test is calculated. If it is false, the values exp1,..., expn, etc. are calculated again. If the value of test is true, the calculation ends with an undefined value of #void. You need to write a function until->transformed, which translates a special form into an expression of the form

```
(let ()
(define (loop)
exp1
...
expn
(if test (void) (loop)))
(loop))
```

I don't quite understand how to do this. I define a function named until->transformed and the arguments exp1..expn, but how do I write the function body to get the expression above? Help me figure it out.

```
(define (until->transformed exp1 ... expn)
( //function body )
)
```

Comment: they probably mean it to be called as in `(until->transformed '(until A B C ... N test))`, with a symbolic expression, which we can emulate by using quoted list as an argument.

Comment: @WillNess, the solution of the problem will be `(define (until->transformed '(until exp1 ... expn test))
(let ()
(define (loop)
exp1
...
expn
(if test (void) (loop)))
(loop))
)`

Comment: try writing it down, and running it, for example after defining it try calling it like `(until->transformed '(until (newline) (set! a (+ a 1)) (> a 10)))`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent you submitting this directly as the answer it:

- intentionally does not transform to the thing you were required to produce, but instead to something different and safer;
- uses bits of Racket you're probably not meant to use.

But I think it should give you the idea.  It also should help explain why writing safe macros in Lisps which don't have hygenic macros is a pain!

```
(define (until-transformed form)
  (match form
    [(list 'until exps ... test)
     (let ([loopn (string->uninterned-symbol "loop")])
       `(let ,loopn ()
          ,@exps
          (if ,test (void) (,loopn))))]
    [x
     (error 'until-transformed "~A is bogus" x)]))
```

Now

```
> (until-transformed '(until (print 1) (print 2) (x? p)))
'(let loop () (print 1) (print 2) (if (x? p) (void) (loop)))
```

but

```
> (until-transformed '(until a))
'(let loop () (if a (void) (loop)))
> (eqv? (second (until-transformed '(until a))) 'loop)
#f
```